# int() not working for floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, int

I recently ran into this in Python 3.5:

```
>>> flt = '3.14'
>>> integer = '5'
>>> float(integer)
5.0
>>> float(flt)
3.14
>>> int(integer)
5
>>> int(flt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    int(flt)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.14'
```

Why is this? It seems like it should return `3`. Am I doing something wrong, or does this happen for a good reason?

Comment: Important point: If you don't assign the result of `float(flt)`, e.g. `flt = float(flt)`, then the converted value is thrown away. It doesn't change its argument in-place (Python has no concept equivalent to C++ pass-by-reference that would allow this), so `int(flt)` is operating on the original `str`, not a `float`. Basically, `int()` works just fine with `float`s, but you didn't give it a `float`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int()` expects an number or string that contains an integer literal. Per the [Python 3.5.2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) documentation:

> If *x* is not a number or if *base* is given, then ***x* must be a string, `bytes`, or `bytearray` instance representing an integer literal** in *radix base*. (Emphasis added)

Meaning `int()` can only convert strings that contain integers. You can easily do this:

```
>>> flt = '3.14'
>>> int(float(flt))
3
```

This will convert `flt` into a float, which is then valid for `int()` because it is a number. Then it will convert to integer by removing fractional parts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why is this? It seems like it should work. I understand that Python does not let you do this, but it seems strange.

Comment: @nedla2004 there's a reason there's a `int` and `float` function. `int` is for integer conversion, `float` is for float conversion. `float` does not convert in place.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

It does not work because `flt` is not a string representation of an integer. You would need to convert it to `float` first then an `int`.

e.g.

```
flt = '3.14'
f = int(float(flt))
```

output is

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already give you a good explanation about your issue, another way to understand what's going would be doing something like this:

```
import sys

for c in ['3.14', '5']:
    try:
        sys.stdout.write(
            "Casting {0} {1} to float({0})...".format(c, c.__class__))
        value = float(c)
        sys.stdout.write("OK -> {0}\n".format(value))
        print('-' * 80)
    except:
        sys.stdout.write("FAIL\n")

    try:
        sys.stdout.write(
            "Casting {0} {1} to int({0})...".format(c, c.__class__))
        value = int(c)
        sys.stdout.write("OK -> {0}\n".format(value))
    except:
        sys.stdout.write("FAIL\n")
        sys.stdout.write("Casting again using int(float({0}))...".format(value))
        value = int(float(c))
        sys.stdout.write("OK -> {0}\n".format(value))
        print('-' * 80)
```

Which outputs:

```
Casting 3.14 <class 'str'> to float(3.14)...OK -> 3.14
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Casting 3.14 <class 'str'> to int(3.14)...FAIL
Casting again using int(float(3.14))...OK -> 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Casting 5 <class 'str'> to float(5)...OK -> 5.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Casting 5 <class 'str'> to int(5)...OK -> 5
```